# Ember + Ember Data Route error handling issue

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-data

In soume routes in my app error action is never triggered and I can't figure out why. On some Routes error action works fine.

This is application route:

```
Simitu.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    Simitu.AuthManager = Simitu.AuthManager.create();
  },
  model: function() {
    if (Simitu.AuthManager.get('session.user'))
      return this.store.find('admin', Simitu.AuthManager.get('session.user'));
  },
  actions: {
    error: function(reason, transition) {
      if (reason.status === 401) {
        Simitu.AuthManager.reset();
        this.transitionTo('login');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

On this route Error is **never triggered**:

```
Simitu.PlacesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var self = this;

    // force adapter request
    this.store.find('place');
    return this.store.filter('place', function(record) {

      // return just places that belongs to this client / application
      return record.get('client_id') === self.modelFor('client');
    });
  },
  actions: {
    createNew: function() {
      var place = this.store.createRecord('place');
          // tree structure in places is not implemented yet
          //parent = this.store.find('place', params.place_id);

      place.set('client_id', this.modelFor('client'));

      // open place
      this.transitionTo('place', place);
    },
    error: function(error, transition) {
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

And on this Route everything works just fine:

```
Simitu.ClientsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('client');
  },
  actions: {
    error: function() {
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

Have anybody some ide why?

Comment: I know this is going to sound like an ass, but is an error occurring, and where and why is it occurring (I realize this isn't what you're trying to solve, but this will help us understand why it may not be calling that action)?

Comment: Api is using token authorisation. I'm simulating token expiration and trying handle HTTP ERROR 401 (unauthorised) in ApplicationRoute (reset authorisation setting in my custom AuthManager class and force transition to login route.

Comment: gotcha, do you have a PlacesRoute?

Comment: yes... here it is:Simitu.PlacesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    error: function() {
      return true;
    }
  }
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `error` action is fired on the resource, not an individual route.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cayidiwa/1/edit

Comment: I don't get it... why error handler works on Application and Clients Route and don't working on the others. How Can I handle this from those places? There is simple but hacky solution with location.reload(); but that pretty sux.
Ember.RSVP.configure('onerror', function(reason) {
  console.log(reason);
  if (reason.status === 401) {
    Simitu.AuthManager.reset();
    window.location.reload();
  }
});

Comment: It's because `Application` and `Clients` are resources in your router.  The `error` action is still hit in the parent's resource, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is how my router looks like. Maybe it breaks because of the nesting or filter logic in models. I fixed it in beforeModel hook in routes but still have not clue what is wrong with my first solution.

```
Simitu.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('login');
  this.resource('clients');
  this.resource('client', { path: 'clients/:client_id'}, function() {
    this.resource('places', function() {
      this.resource('place', { path: ':place_id' });
    });
    this.resource('placecategories',{ path: 'places-categories' }, function() {
      this.route('new');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I move some of auth handling logic to **beforeModel** hook.

```
Simitu.AuthRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function(transition) {
    if (!Simitu.AuthManager.isAutenticated()) {
      this.redirectToLogin(transition);
    }
  },
  redirectToLogin: function(transition) {
    this.transitionTo('login');
  },
  actions: {
    error: function(reason, transition) {
      if (reason.status === 401) {
        Simitu.AuthManager.reset();
        this.redirectToLogin(transoition);
      }
    }
  }
});
```